# use of "by the time" in this example of past narrative

Tags: tense, tense-agreement

> John wanted to go home but didn't want to wait for the bus, so he
>   started to walk. After all, the wait wasn't worth it; by the time the bus
>   **would** come, he **would be** home already.

Is this the right use of the tenses in this example of "by the time"?
If not, which is the one(or ones)?

Comment: Are you asking if “would” is used correctly? What are your hesitations about this sentence as written?

Comment: yes, I mean would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use "by" with a time it simply means that something will be done *before* that time.

For example:

> I will have my homework done by 5 o'clock.

This means that your homework will be finished *before* that time.

In your example, it uses a *comparative* time and means that the time John expected to wait for a bus to arrive was *greater* than the time it would take him to walk home, so it was not worth his while waiting.

The tense is dictated by when the events you are comparing would occur. In your example, you already said that it "wasn't" worth waiting. As this is already the past tense the following sentence should read:

> By the time the bus **came**, he would be home already.

Alternatively, if the rest of the narrative were in the present tense you could use the future tense for your statement in question:

> It **isn't** worth waiting. By the time the bus **comes** I **will** be home.

Comment: I know what it means (I created the sentence). The question I posted is different

Comment: @Fra Quite right, sorry. I've added to my answer. I was trying to establish the point about comparative times. You will see from my answer that the tense you are asking about hangs on what else you have said.